# useState hook causes "too many rerenders" error when using it in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-state

I just started with React-native and I can't understand why I got error "too many rerenders".
So I created app using npx react-native init command and than I changed App.js, now my App.js looks like that:

```
const App = () => {
    const [numberOne, setNumberOne] = useState(0);
    const [numberTwo, setNumberTwo] = useState(0);

    setNumberOne(5);
    setNumberTwo(7);

    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Number one is {numberOne}</Text>
            <Text>Number two is {numberTwo}</Text>
        </View>
    )
};
```

Also I was trying to use seters inside a function but got same error:

```
const App = () => {
    const [numberOne, setNumberOne] = useState(0);
    const [numberTwo, setNumberTwo] = useState(0);

    const set = () => {
        setNumberOne(5);
        setNumberTwo(7);
    };

    set();

    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Number one is {numberOne}</Text>
            <Text>Number two is {numberTwo}</Text>
        </View>
    )
};
```

Why is this happens and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are changing the component's state when it renders. Also, when a component's state changes, it will render again. Thus, you are getting an infinite loop of renders.

*Renders => updates state on render => renders again because the state changed => updates state again because it rendered again => ...*

What you can probably try is something like this:

```
const App = () => {
    const [numberOne, setNumberOne] = useState(0);
    const [numberTwo, setNumberTwo] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        setNumberOne(5);
        setNumberTwo(7);
    }, []);

    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Number one is {numberOne}</Text>
            <Text>Number two is {numberTwo}</Text>
        </View>
    )
};
```

That will schedule an effect to be run only after the first render, because you are passing an empty dependencies array as second argument of the `useEffect` hook.

You don't have to define a setter, your `setNumberOne` and `setNumberTwo` are already "setters", that then you can use in event handlers